# Refreshing on <form> submittal not working

Tags: javascript, html

I know there have been similar questions like this one in the past, but none of them really help. I have asked one before, but that was different.

In this code snippet, what is making the page refresh? I know to put `return false;` in my js, but I have put it everywhere and it does not seem to work.

```
<p style="color: lime;">Password:</p>
<form name="pass" method="post" onsubmit="passhandler()">
<input name="passinp" required autocomplete="off" type="text"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<p id="inco"></p>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
function passhandler() {
alert("test");
var pass = document.forms.["pass"]["passinp"].value;

if (pass == "ash.is.alight") {
    href("homepage-password=198rwre92r97yr29739723ry23e7y.html");

} else {
document.getElementById("inco").innerHTML = "Password incorrect!";
}
}
</script>
```

Even the `alert("test")` does not work, which makes me think the problem is in the form element. Again, thanks!

Comment: `var pass = document.forms["pass"]["passinp"].value;`
 this is the correct syntax

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate of other questions, you should explain why by pointing out which suggestions didn’t work for you instead of telling us not to close it in all-caps. If you also tell us to not downvote, it’s most likely a question that needs to be downvoted.

Comment: @Xufox I'm a bit desperate, as this is urgent, forgive me for any crudeness.

Comment: It’s based on a syntax error. Just open the browser console and you’ll see the error message, without the need to ask on this site…

Comment: @Xufox thankyou, it's just that I did not understand that.

Comment: @Xufox But it is still refreshing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

```
function passhandler() {
var pass = document.forms["pass"]["passinp"].value;


if (pass == "ash.is.alight") {
    window.location.replace("homepage- password=198rwre92r97yr29739723ry23e7y.html");
    return false;

} else {
document.getElementById("inco").innerHTML = "Password incorrect!";
return false;

}

}
```

Thank you Amresh for correcting the `<form>` syntax!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (element.addEventListener) {
  element.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.history.back();
  }, true);
 }
else {
  element.attachEvent('onsubmit', function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault();
      window.history.back();
  });
 }
```